# How to use CASE in WHERE dynamically ? With datetime selection

Tags: t-sql, case, where-clause

I have a select which needs to have dynamic WHERE CASE conditions.

```
SELECT 
      *
FROM 
      vwShowUctyPohyby
WHERE
      (@id_parent is null or id_parent=@id_parent)
      and (datetime_creation <= @record_first_datetime)
ORDER BY 
      CASE @sort_order WHEN 0 THEN datetime_creation END ASC, 
      CASE @sort_order WHEN 1 THEN datetime_creation END DESC
```

As you can see there is a condition to dynamically choose type of `ORDER`. Now I need to do same with `WHERE` part. I found that it can work like datetime_creation = CASE ..... WHEN ... THEN .... END.

Problem is that I need to create `datetime_creation <= @record_first_datetime` for one WHERE condition and `datetime_creation >= @record_first_datetime` for other condition.

How do I do that? I dont want to create two selects and use IF ELSE statement.

I am using this SELECT for dynamic paging on SQL side, with ROWCOUNT.

Comment: the CASE can used for column values (field level), not on part of statements. you will have to create two statements, even if you dont like this.

Comment: Thank you, you could do this as proper answer I would like to rate it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this your intention ?

```
SELECT  * 
FROM  vwShowUctyPohyby 
WHERE 
      (@id_parent is null or id_parent=@id_parent) 
      and 
      ((datetime_creation <= @record_first_datetime and @sort_order = 0) or
      (datetime_creation >= @record_first_datetime and @sort_order = 1))
ORDER BY  
      CASE @sort_order WHEN 0 THEN datetime_creation END ASC,  
      CASE @sort_order WHEN 1 THEN datetime_creation END DESC
```